# Generate JSON using JAXB annotations,Jackson and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, jaxb, jackson

I am trying to implement a REST service using Spring 4.

The application is built using Java 7 and runs on Tomcat 7.

The REST method will return a customer object in JSON. The application is annotation-driven.

The Customer class has JAXB annotations. 
Jackson jars are present in the class path. As per my understanding Jackson will use JAXB annotations to generate the JSON.

**The Customer Class :**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
private int id;
private String name;
private List favBookList;
@XmlAttribute
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
@XmlElement
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "booklist")
@XmlElement(name="book")
public List getFavBookList() {
return favBookList;
}
public void setFavBookList(List favBookList) {
this.favBookList = favBookList;
}
}
```

I have annotated the REST service class as @RestController (as per Spring 4)

**The REST method to return a customer object in JSON:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer.json",produces="application/json")
public  Customer getCustomerInJSON(){
    Customer customerObj = new  Customer();
    customerObj.setId(1);
    customerObj.setName("Vijay");
    ArrayList<String> favBookList = new ArrayList<String>();
    favBookList.add("Book1");
    favBookList.add("Book2");
    customerObj.setFavBookList(favBookList);
    return customerObj;

}
```

**The result I expected, when I hit the URL :**

```
{"id":1,"booklist":{"book":["Book1","Book2"]},"name":"Vijay"}
```

**What I get:**

```
{"id":1,"name":"Vijay","favBookList":["Book1","Book2"]}
```

It seems Jackson is ignoring the JAXB annotations **@XmlElementWrapper(name = "booklist")** and
**@XmlElement(name="book")** above getFavBookList() method in Customer class

Am I missing something?

Need guidance. Thanks.

Comment: put these annotations on variable declaration, and check

Comment: tried that. still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the point is, you have given xml annotations and are expecting Json output.

You need to find out Json equivalent for its xml counter part `@xmlElementWrapper`.

This feature used to work in jackson 1.x but does not in Jackson 2.x

Comment: Thanks for that note. However, I use Jackson 1.9. 
Need to check that.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution with Jackson. However I came across a discussion in which the required JSON can be achieved using MOXy

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735245/jaxb-jackson-handling-arrays?answertab=active#tab-top

On second thoughts, I feel my required JSON does not represent a natural JSON. The result I currently get seems to represent a natural JSON result.

I can annotate the list using **@JsonProperty("bookList")**

Any thoughts?

Comment: yes you are going right, but both Json are valid , whichever suits you best  use it